# Instant app zip uploading error

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to publish my first InstantApp. It's a brand new app, so I first published the app in the "`installed way`" and when I tried uploading the `instant-app.zip` I got the error:

***Upload failed***

***You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: NO_SIG_FOR_TARGET_SANDBOX_VERSION: Missing APK Signature Scheme v2 signature required for target sandbox version 2 ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES: No JAR signatures.***

I thought it was the lacking of signing key and signed using gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias 'somealias'
        keyPassword 'somepass'
        storeFile file("$rootDir/some.jks")
        storePassword 'some'
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Does anyone passed through this issue?

Comment: Can you check whether every "feature" module has the same "signingConfigs" block specified?

Comment: That was not the problem @dchai. The instant app does not use the settings from build.gradle (don't know why). I was able to solve the problem, I had signing it using the AS signing dialog and checking signjar and v2 full checkboxes in the bottom of the signing dialog!

Comment: > don't know why
FYI: If you're using Gradle from the command line, you need to specify "signingConfigs" in each build.gradle file.  That's a limitation of the current plugin.

Comment: weird, I tried that and it didn't work. Does not generate apk! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like Play is seeing an APK which is not signed at all. There are two error messages: (1) that there's no APK Signature Scheme v2 signature (this is required for Instant Apps), and (2) that there's no JAR signature (this is required if the app's minSdkVersion is lower than 24).

To check whether your APK is properly signed:

```
apksigner verify -v my.apk
```

Try this for every APK inside the ZIP you're uploading.

Comment: do you have a reference for point 1 (the fact that V2 is required for IA)? I'd like to read more on that